# MySQL changed password not working

Tags: mysql, linux

I needed to change mysql root password on host localhost, 127.0.0.1 and %. Locally, in the server I can login with the new password. But on remote machines this isn't the case. I tried entering the old password and it logs in. What's the cause for this??? anyone

I double checked and is the same mysql server instance... MySQL is running on a Linux Fedora installation

Comment: Show how you're trying to change the password.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Logins from remote clients are authenticated based on the credentials that you define in the privileges.  The root password is only used to authenticate the root user.

Comment: But I can actually log in with mysql root user from a remote machine...the old one!

Comment: Did you update the record for the root user in the mysql.user table, and flush the privileges?

Comment: forgot to flush privileges...It works now thanks